# Insert Checkbox in Dygraph

Tags: r, dygraphs

http://dygraphs.com/tests/visibility.html

Anybody know the code to create a checkbox for dygraphs?

Here is an example code:

```
 Date     A      B  
 8/1      5      6
 8/2      6      9
 8/3      2      4
```

I want to create a checkbox that will give you the option to choose A,B, or both.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm referring to hiasel solution from [here](https://github.com/rstudio/dygraphs/issues/63)

You can do it by following these simple 3 steps:-
1)Get the hide.js file from [here](https://github.com/rstudio/dygraphs/commit/a4e3553005a021fbf597b97ed5b9170f37bb611c) and place it in \dygraphs\plugins folder.

2) define the function in

```
dyHide <-function(dygraph) {
dyPlugin(
dygraph = dygraph,
name = "Hide",
path = system.file("plugins/hide.js", package = "dygraphs")
)
}
```

3) add it to your graph using `%>% dyHide()`

Answer (score 0):

Simply view the source of the example page...

```
   <html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7; IE=EmulateIE9">
    <title>visibility</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../dygraph-dev.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="data.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Click the check boxes to toggle series visibility</h3>
    <div id="div_g" style="width:600px; height:300px;"></div>

    <p><b>Show Series:</b></p>
    <p>
      <input type=checkbox id="0" onClick="change(this)">
      <label for="0"> A</label><br/>
      <input type=checkbox id="1" checked onClick="change(this)">
      <label for="1"> B</label><br/>
      <input type=checkbox id="2" checked onClick="change(this)">
      <label for="2"> C</label>
    </p>

    <p>g.visibility() = <span id="visibility"></span></p>


    <script type="text/javascript">
      g = new Dygraph(
            document.getElementById("div_g"),
            NoisyDataABC, {
              rollPeriod: 7,
              errorBars: true,
              visibility: [false, true, true]
            }
          );
      setStatus();

      function setStatus() {
        document.getElementById("visibility").innerHTML =
          g.visibility().toString();
      }

      function change(el) {
        g.setVisibility(parseInt(el.id), el.checked);
        setStatus();
      }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's not in R code though, I'm using RStudio. @katz

Comment: @analytics - did you ever figure out how to do this in R?

Comment: Doesn't help with doing it in R, but for people who have this question and are using the JavaScript library directly see https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/issues/355